# error in converting kml to geojson

Tags: javascript, jquery, kml, geojson

I am trying to convert a KML file into geojson for D3. But it encountered the following error:

> getElementsByTagName() is not a function

while running following script in browser.

```
<script>
                $.ajax('data/District.kml').done(function(xml) {
                    console.log(toGeoJSON.kml(xml));
</script>
```

I have tried in both google chrome and firefox.

Comment: u can this link http://www.thomasfrank.se/xml_to_json.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, finally I got a link that converts KML file into geojson.

> http://ogre.adc4gis.com/